# string.Replace() doesn't update the string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I tried use the string.Replace() function, but it doesn't work right.

```
string test = "AAA AA AA faseffs AEfAfse AFAEf AEFAEf";
test.Replace('A', 'C');
label.Text = test;
```

`label` shows me the `test` string without replacing anything.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strings are immutable in NET. Replace works building a new string with the replaced chars and returning it. You could assign the returned string to the same string used to call the Replace method (or to a new string variable)

```
test = test.Replace('A', 'C');
```